# Map output based on Filter RDD- PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have been trying to get two different outputs based on filter RDD values.
I have a text2 RDD with value like

```
text=["values are defined in config file"]

text2=sc.parallelize(text)
text2.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")).filter(lambda y:'key' in y).map(lambda x: ('key',0) if len(x)==0  else ('key',1)).collect()
```

if 'key' is there in text2 then i should get

```
('key',1)
```

else i should get

```
('key',0)
```

'key' is not there in the text but i am still getting an empty value as [].
can somebody point me out what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misuse of `in`. Can you try code below

```
text2 \
  .flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")) \
  .map(lambda y: ('key', int(y==key))).collect()
```

But i guess you dont want to flat map its possible to you are looking for this:

```
text2 \
  .map(lambda x: x.split(" ")) \
  .map(lambda y: ('key', int(key in y))).collect()
```

Comment: getting the entire values 
['values', 'are', 'defined', 'in', 'config', 'file']

Comment: the output should be ('key',0) if word 'key' not found .. if found it should be ('key',1)